# How do you simplify radicals with numerator

Tags: radicals

Square root of 18/3

I don't understand how you simplify this. No clue, I only understand to simplify the denominator. Thank You

Comment: How about just simplifying the fraction $\frac{18}{3}$? Or did you instead mean $\frac{\sqrt{18}}{3}$?

Comment: is it $\sqrt{\frac{18}{3}}$? or is it $\frac{\sqrt{18}}{3}$?

Comment: 18√3 how do you simplify this?

Comment: It's supposed to be √18/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user113293 $$\frac{\sqrt{18}}{3}=\frac{\sqrt{9}\sqrt{2}}{3}=\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{3}=\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about $\frac{\sqrt{18}}{3}$  then $18=9 \cdot 2$ thus $\sqrt{18}=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{2}=3\sqrt{2}$.

If you want to simplify instead $\sqrt{\frac{18}{3}}$ then just simplify $18/3$.

Comment: Thank you. 3√2 is the right answer. I felt like I had to do a lot more to simplify that.

Comment: @user113293 The final answer is then $\frac{3 \sqrt{2}}{3}=\sqrt{2}$...

Comment: Wait, so were did you get the 3 on the denominator?